# Is it possible to install ubuntu 13.04 from 3 GB flashdrive

Tags: usb

I want to install Ubuntu (fresh Install) but i only have this 3GB flash drive to install from.is it possible or do i have to go to the store? and is it also possible to install from 4 GB?

Comment: 3 GB flash drve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeking to install from a Flash drive,  a 3 GB drive should suffice. If the flash drive is using a USB 3.0 port, that will be faster, but a USB 2.0 port should work fine as well (USB 1.1 is going to be very slow by comparison).

There is a very detailed, step-by-step guide on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) that thoroughly discusses the entire process and should be sufficient to be able to allow you to install from a USB Flash drive from various operating systems and in different scenarios.

Do hope that is helpful as this is an easy process once you have the USB Flash drive setup.

Comment: Glad that helped. :)